# Show that if u · x = v · x for any vector x, then u = v.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, vectors

I know that the dot product of a 2d vector (a, b) * (c, d) is equivalent to ac + bd. From this I got that **u** = (a, b), **x** = (c, d), and **v** = (e, f). That leads to ac + bd = ec + fd. In the end, I know I need to show that a = e and b = f. If I switch some stuff around and factor, I can get c(a - e) = d(f - b), but I don't know where to go from here. Is there a logical (geometrical) way to prove this or an algebraic way to prove the commutative property in vectors?

Comment: Put $x = u-v$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Another way to state the hypothesis is that $(u - v) \cdot x = 0$ for any vector $x$. First prove that if $w \cdot x = 0$ for any vector $x$ then $w = 0$. Then apply that result to the vector $u - v$ to conclude that $u - v = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot product is distributive, so

$$u \cdot x - v \cdot x = x \cdot (u-v)=0$$

From this, we can conclude that either

- $x$ is the zero vector
- $u-v$ is the zero vector, from which it follows that $u=v$
- Both $x$ and $u-v$ are the zero vector
- $x$ and $u-v$ are orthogonal

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If $u\cdot x = v\cdot x$ for *any* vector $x$, then $u\cdot x = v\cdot x$ for the $specific$ vectors $x=x_1=(1,0)$ and $x=x_2=(0,1)$.

$u\cdot x_1=v\cdot x_1$ gives one equation; $u\cdot x_2=v\cdot x_2$ gives another.  What are those two equations and what can you conclude from putting them together?

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped!